# Problem creating O365 Group using Graph API

Tags: azure-ad-graph-api, o365-flow

I am trying to create O365 Group using Graph API, though I am able to get users and user profile details, I am unable to create group. My Azure tenant does have permission to create users/groups in the default directory and I did gave Profile and GroupReadWriteAll permissions.

static async Task CreateO365Group(string o365Group)
        {
            try
            {
                //Get the Graph client
                var graphClient = AuthenticationHelper.GetAuthenticatedClient();

```
            var token = await AuthenticationHelper.GetTokenForUserAsync();

            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, graphClient.BaseUrl + "/groups");
            request.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

            var group = new Group
            {
                Description = "Group for Partners",
                DisplayName = "O365Partners",
                GroupTypes = new List<String>()
                {
                    "Unified"
                },
                MailEnabled = true,
                MailNickname = "library",
                SecurityEnabled = false
            };

            await graphClient.Groups.Request().AddAsync(group);

            var response = await graphClient.HttpProvider.SendAsync(request);
            var bodyContents = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            Debug.WriteLine(bodyContents);
            return bodyContents;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
           Debug.WriteLine("Could not create Group {0} {1}", e.Message,o365Group);
           return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: "Code: MethodNotAllowed\r\nMessage: Method not allowed.\r\nInner error:\r\n\tAdditionalData:\r\n\trequest-id: 88ee1b7f-0fe3-43d8-b476-5594621588b6\r\n\tdate: 11/25/2019 07:18:49\r\nClientRequestId: 88ee1b7f-0fe3-43d8-b476-5594621588b6\r\n"

Comment: I have figured out the issue, I was using my live id. I have created a user in Azure AD and then tried, picked a plum!

Comment: Great! You could add an answer and make it marked to help other people who have the same issue.

Comment: Can I mark my comment as answer myself?

Comment: You can post an **answer** and mark it as accepted.